# VOIP call all numbers from list/text file

Tags: mysql, voip

I'm looking for a way to call multiple numbers from a list.

I want to make a test calls to check what numbers are working and  what not. It's not for making robocalls, but our DID suppliers sometimes fails and I want to every week make 1200 calls to test if they are working.

It would be best if it could be implemented in some form of php panel.

I want to make all those calls then grab data from SQL billing server and check if number is working or not

Comment: Create a cli script in your favourite language and get all the data from the database, then use a loop to call all the numbers.

Comment: You described your high level requirements, but failed to ask a single question!

Answer (score 0):

Check opensource projects like vicibox. It have dialling core source, where you can get idea how to do calls.

There can be many issues in path, use already writted code if possible.